# SwiftUI Location Manager

Tags: swiftui, core-location

I've made an app that user CoreLocation to get users latitude and longitude, I want to help users find each other by providing a general direction to them to find their friend (CoreMotion and animations to rotate an image), but after about 60 seconds I get this error:

```
2023-08-31 18:11:12.121959+0200 TrackMe[10753:3030019] [GEOXPC] Throttled "PlaceRequest.REQUEST_TYPE_REVERSE_GEOCODING" request: Tried to make more than 50 requests in 60 seconds, will reset in 37 seconds - Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-3 "(null)" UserInfo={details=(
        {
        intervalType = short;
        maxRequests = 50;
        "throttler.keyPath" = "app:Username.AppName/0x20304/short(default/any)";
        timeUntilReset = 37;
        windowSize = 60;
    }
), requestKindString=PlaceRequest.REQUEST_TYPE_REVERSE_GEOCODING, timeUntilReset=37, requestKind=772}
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 2.)
```

Is there something that Im doing wrong? I have implemented my locationManager as follows:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    @Published var locationName: String?
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
  
    func requestLocation(){
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let lastLocation = locations.last {
            location = lastLocation.coordinate
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: lastLocation.coordinate,
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)
            )
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 60) {
                let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
                       let location = CLLocation(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                       
                       geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
                           if let error = error {
                               print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                           } else if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                               let loc = placemark.name ?? "Unknown Area"
                               self.locationName = loc
                   }
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my view is running this

```
    private func calculateDirection() -> Double {
        guard let userLocation = locationManager.location else {
            return 0.0
        }

        let userHeading = motionManager.deviceOrientation
        let targetLocation = CLLocation(latitude: Double(userLat) ?? 0.0, longitude: Double(userLong) ?? 0.0)
        let dx = targetLocation.coordinate.longitude - userLocation.longitude
        let dy = targetLocation.coordinate.latitude - userLocation.latitude
              let angle = atan2(dy, dx)

              let degrees = userHeading.radiansToDegrees + angle.radiansToDegrees
              return degrees
    }
}
```

Comment: As you make location  accuracy to best you get very frequent location update. For each update you try get a reverse location to get the name of the place. This happens too often for the system and that cause your error. You should have a timer fire every few seconds to find reverse location of the current user location saved in your ObservableObject.